# How to write JUnit test for switch case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

For example, method `switchCase()`. How do I write test code for it? I can just create 3 different tests just with different values for each test, respective to the switch case value, but I want to try a more efficient way of doing this.

```
    @InjectMocks
    private RepoFactory repoFactory;
```

```
    public void switchCase() {
            ConsentApplication consentApplication = repoFactory.getConsentApplicationRepo()
.findOne(consentApplicationVo.getId());

        switch (CrestApiServiceNameEnum.getByCode(serviceNameEnum.getCode())) {
            case CUST_DATA:
                newCrestApiTrack.setRepRefNo(null);
                httpHeaders.add("API-KEY", custDataApiKey);
                break;
            case CREDIT_PARAM:
                httpHeaders.add("API-KEY", creditParamApiKey);
                break;
            case CONFIRM_MUL_ENT:
                httpHeaders.add("API-KEY", multiEntitiApiKey);
                break;
            default:
                LOGGER.info("Unexpected value: " + CrestApiServiceNameEnum.getByCode(serviceNameEnum.getCode()));
        }
    }
```

What I tried was, using `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)`, `@ValueSource` and `@ParameterizedTest`. However, this always produces `NullPointerException` at the first `when` and `java.lang.Exception: Method testSwitchCase_SUCCESS should have no parameters`. Can help me on this?

```
   @ParameterizedTest
   @ValueSource(strings = {"value1", "value2"})
   void testSwitchCase_SUCCESS(String s) {

      //have something

             when(repoFactory.getConsentApplicationRepo().findOne(anyString()))
                .thenReturn(consentApplication);

   }
```

Comment: Separate UI and IO (getting data from the User or from the disk/network) from the logic transforming the data -  your code will be easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your test either with `@Test` or `@ParameterizedTest` but not both.

From the [JUnit 5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests):

> Parameterized tests make it possible to run a test multiple times with different arguments. They are declared just like regular `@Test` methods **but use the `@ParameterizedTest` annotation instead**.

Also the `@RunWith` annotation is from JUnit 4. When using JUnit 5 this annotation is unnecessary and should be removed.

Then, as Lesiak has commented: you should separate IO and logic. A method the receives the string to switch on as parameter and returns an object is much easier to test than a method that does everything: read data from the user, operates on it and produce some terminal output.

---

It seems that you have a mix of JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 annotations. That doesn't really work. If you want to use JUnit 5 then remove all uses of `org.junit.Test` and `org.junit.runner.RunWith` from your test class and replace them with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith`.

Comment: So, I followed the advice and I put the actual code here. However, I still getting ```NullPointerException``` at ```when```. @Lesiak @Thomas Kläger

Comment: @user14144231 there are two cases where `when(repoFactory.getConsentApplicationRepo().findOne(anyString()))` can throw a `NullPointerException`: either `repoFactory` is null or `repoFactory.getConsentApplicationRepo()` is null. You need to find out which one of these two cases you have.

Comment: I noticed its because of  `repoFactory` is `null` when using `ParameterizedTest`, but it's okay when using `Test`.

Comment: @user14144231 Is your test class annotated with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`? Without this annotation JUnit 5 will not know what to do with `@InjectMocks`. If there is no NPE when annotating the test with `@Test` then your class is maybe annotated with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` - but that again is a JUnit 4 annotation that JUnit 5 ignores.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found a solution, the class should be annotated with `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` and `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and the in `setup`, we should put `initMocks(this);`. However, this will only mock a non-static class.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    initMocks(this);
    setupRepos();
    setupLoginUser();
    setupUserLoginReturn();
    setupLoggerAppender();
}
```